# API issue in Woocommerce/WordPress/Hostinger

Tags: wordpress

[image]

1. When the stock quantity is updated from the API Request, Stock Quantity in Admin Panel is changed.
2. But the stock quantity in response of the API(Read) and the Add To Cart Page in Customer Side are not changed and it’s not OK.
3. The stock quantity is changed for these two about 5~10mins and so on.
4. In the other side, when the stock quantity is updated from the Admin Panel, all of these are changed and it’s OK.

Please kindly assist me
Why should I do it?

Find and fix the problem.